# virtualhost access only to localhost

Tags: apache, cakephp, virtualhost, ampps

I created a virtualhost to a cakephp application:

I set the **httpd-vhosts.conf** this way:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
   ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot /Applications/AMPPS/www/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.drin.com
        ServerAlias www.drin.com drin.com
        DocumentRoot /Applications/AMPPS/www/carte_drin/app/webroot

        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #disable htaccess starting at /
       <Directory />
                AllowOverride none
       </Directory>

       <Directory /Applications/AMPPS/www/carte_drin/app/webroot/>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

                <Files sitemap.xml>
                        RewriteEngine Off
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the **/etc/hosts** file this way also:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1 www.drin.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

yet when I try to access to www.drin.com it points me to localhost page not to the application itself. I'm using AMPPS under MAC. If you know what's going wrong tell me.

Best

Comment: You've restarted Apache after updating the config, right?

Comment: Try a ping of www.drin.com, does it resolve to 127.0.0.1?  Depending how your system is configured, it might resolve to something else.

Comment: I did restart the apache when I finished the config

Comment: The result of ping : PING www.drin.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms and so on.

Comment: I need to create a virtualhost to get rid of the .htaccess files. I use them and the application works although the other projects under www don't because the .htaccess under  www points to the current one I'm working on.